# Parsing JSON data in flutter that has a null key

Tags: json, flutter, dart, model, flutter-layout

I have a json data that I used a website to parse(this is the site: https://javiercbk.github.io/json_to_dart/ ) but I got an error that the model was not correct and that is because my json data contains a list that has a list and in that list, another list that contains the keys and their values but there is a key which is null in that list..I put the json data below for better understanding..My question is, "is there any way that I can create a model and skip over the null key and work with the other available keys and values?"

```
{
    "result": {
        "newsfeed": [
            [
                null,
                {
                    "author": "5f177c2139e3390017e71c70",
                    "userTag": "",
                    "text": "try this one",
                    "video": "",
                    "image": "",
                    "createdAt": "Wed Sep 16 2020 09:28:00 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time)",
                    "name": "",
                    "campus": ""
                }
            ],
            [
                null,
                {
                    "author": "5f177d2739e3390017e71c71",
                    "userTag": "bigjo",
                    "text": "yooooo",
                    "video": "",
                    "image": "",
                    "createdAt": "Wed Sep 16 2020 09:28:00 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time)",
                    "name": "",
                    "campus": "Bells University Of Technology"
                }
            ]
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you can assign some other value to it instead of null.

```
x['result']['newsfeed'].forEach((element){
    element[0] = element[1];  //or any other object
}
```

This might not be the best way to do it though.

Comment: Okay, I'll try that

Answer (score 0):

I also just had such issues. You can use QuickType to generate the mapping code for you based on the JSON input.
I am using factory for JSON decoding and for optional values the line would be something like

```
taskPic: parsedJson["taskPic"] == null ? null : parsedJson['taskPic'],
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I used Quicktype io to generate a model before but when it was time to display the snapshot data I encountered an issue showing the other elements in the snapshot (what I mean is snapshot.data.result.newsfeed[index].name gives an error at .name)... I will try using your option also